# Gitlab Runner with Docker and shell error — Permission denied

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Installed a brand new Gitlab CE 13.9.1 on a Ubuntu Server 20.04.2.0.
This is the pipeline

```
image: node:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq

stages:
  - install

install:
  stage: install
  script:
    - npm install --verbose
```

To run it I configure my Gitlab Runner using the same procedure as in my previous Gitlab CE 12:

I pull last Gitlab runner image:

```
docker pull gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

---

**First try:**

Start GitLab Runner container mounting on local volume

```
docker run -d \
--name gitlab-runner \
--restart always \
-v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

And register runner

```
docker run --rm -t -i \
-v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register
```

When registering runner, for executor I pick `shell`

Finally, when I push to Gitlab, on the pipeline, I see this error:

```
$ apt-get update -qq
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

---

**Second try:**

Start GitLab Runner container mounting on Docker volume

1. Create volume

```
docker volume create gitlab-runner-config
```

2. Start GitLab Runner container

```
docker run -d \
--name gitlab-runner \
--restart always \
-v gitlab-runner-config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
```

3. Register runner (picking shell again as executor)

```
docker run \
--rm -t -i \
-v gitlab-runner-config:/etc/gitlab-runner gitlab/gitlab-runner register
```

Same results.

```
$ apt-get update -qq
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

---

**Third try:**

Granting permissions to gitlab-runner

I ended up reading [In gitlab CI the gitlab runner choose wrong executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678061/in-gitlab-ci-the-gitlab-runner-choose-wrong-executor) and https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html#running-as-unprivileged-user, which states these solutions:

> 1. move to docker
> 2. grant user gitlab-runner the permissions he needs to run specified commands. gitlab-runner may run apt-get without sudo, also he will need perms for npm install and npm run.
> 3. grant sudo nopasswd to user gitlab-runner. Add gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL (or similar) to /etc/sudoers on the machine gitlab-runner is installed and change the lines apt-get update to sudo apt-get update, which will execute them as privileged user (root).

1. I need to use `shell`
2. I already did that with `sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner`
3. Tried as well with `sudo nano /etc/sudoers`, adding `gitlab-runner ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`, and using `sudo apt-get update -qq` in the pipeline, which results in `bash: line 106: sudo: command not found`

I'm pretty lost here now. Any idea will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, using `shell` executor on a Docker runner with already mounted Docker socket on it is not a good idea. You'd better **use `docker` executor**, which will take care of everything and probably is how it's supposed to be run.

#### Edit

Alternatively, you can use a customized Docker image to allow using the shell executor with `root` permissions. First, you'll need to create a `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
# Change user to root
USER root
```

Then, you'll have to build the image (here, I tagged it as `custom-gitlab-runner`):

```sh
$ docker build -t custom-gitlab-runner .
```

Finally, you'll need to use this image:

```sh
docker run -d \
  --name gitlab-runner \
  --restart always \
  -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  custom-gitlab-runner:latest
```

Comment: As stated in the question shell is a requirement.

Comment: This is not stated as a requirement. Furthermore, you are configuring everything as if you are going to use the `docker` executor (using Docker In Docker).

Comment: Please refer to the title of the question. I'm aware about the configuration of the pipeline as if I were going to use it with docker executor; the interesting thing here is that I had it running this pipeline with Gitlab Runner 12 with shell executor. Should work this way, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `Please refer to the title of the question` It's not stating it as a requirement, either. The posted solution is -at least- an adequate one, as it fixes the error (just change `shell` to `docker` and everything will work). Downvote is not fair, or edit your question and ensure `shell` is stated as a requirement (which will be difficult to understand, but will be your specific question).

Comment: You are in reason, just edit the answer in anyway so I can unvote it

Comment: Added alternate solution

Comment: Using your solution,seems to work, tons of thanks.

Comment: Note: The _alternate solution_ may have some security implications and other kind of errors (for example, think about side effects).

Comment: `tons of thanks` You're welcome :) Please, also mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: «The alternate solution may have some security implications»: true, going with docker executor is definitely the way to go

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue trying to use locally installed gitlab-runner on ubuntu with a shell executor (I had other issues using docker executor not being able to communicate between stages)

```
$ docker build -t myapp .
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B%5D&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=1&shmsize=0&t=myapp&target=&ulimits=null&version=1": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I then printed what user  was running the docker command within the gitlab-ci.yml file, which was `gitlab-runner`

```
...

build:
  script:
    - echo $USER
    - docker build -t myapp .
...
```

I then added `gitlab-runner` to the docker group using

```
sudo usermod -aG docker gitlab-runner
```

which fixed my issue. No more docker permission errors.